# is the name Vincent in Japanese ヴィンセント or ビンセント?

Tags: pronunciation, names

I've seen different answers and I am relatively new to learning Japanese, I never knew they had V characters, and would spelling vincent like ヴィンセント change the pronunciation or would it still be with a b sound?